# xaml Property ItemTemplate does not have a value

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to make a GridView in XAML and show elements inside it, but it is an error.

```
 <GridView ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Tapped="RealisticNav" Margin="28,55,21,0" Width="300" Height="300" Background="#271813" Opacity="0.8" CornerRadius="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >

                        <StackPanel Width="300" Height="300">
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="200" Width="288" Margin="10" Stretch="Fill" />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="R"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Text="{Binding RealisticEntity}" FontSize="50"  Height="70" />
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>
```

in addition to the x:Name="R" element inside this GridView seems like cannot be accessed have the following error "The name 'R' does not exist in the current context" in C# file

I'm using VS 2013

Comment: why do you want to access to textblock?

Comment: And why do you need name for binding? Just do it in XAML code

Answer (score 0):

You define the x:Name="R" inside a data template which means that you're not defining that the page includes this element, you're declaring a **template** from which .NET can create elements.

DataTemplate may be on the page any number of times, and can even change while running. The .Net doesn't know which "R" field should be linked and this is why there is no access to "R", it simply wasn't created.

This is the error.

If you want to bind you need to use item source like that:

```
<GridView ItemSource="{Binding yourSource IsItemClickEnabled="True">

//All the code between

<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />

//All the code between

</GridView>
```